# Why arr[i][j-1] = zero?

Tags: arrays, c

Why is the arr[i][j-1] zero? After testing using the `printf` function, it shows that the position is `arr[0][-1]` and it has the value 0 as it appears from the results below.

```
int main() {
int arr [2][4];
int i,j;



for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("Provide a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]); // get the values
        printf("The arr[i][j] is %d\n",arr[i][j]);
        printf("The arr[i][j-1] is %d\n",arr[i][j-1]);             
    }
}
//print the values
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i][j]);
}
}
}
```

Example of how it works:

```
Provide a number: 12
The arr[i][j] is 12
The arr[i][j-1] is 0
Provide a number: 14
The arr[i][j] is 14
The arr[i][j-1] is 12
Provide a number:
```

If the following `arr[i][j-2]` is used though, then it shows this:

```
The arr[i][j-2] is 6611520
```

this is typical in C but the `0` in `j-1` is not clear. Can you explain?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: the `arr[i][j-1]`?

Comment: When i is equal to 0 and j = 0.

Comment: You mean arr[0][0] is undefined behavior? Since 0 is the first index in C why does this happen? Please explain what do you mean. Or you mean in this case the -1 causes undefined behavior?

Comment: I mean the expression arr[i][j-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[0][-1]` is outside the bounds of the array.

Reading or writing outside the bounds of an array (or even creating a pointer to such an element) triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Loosely speaking, this means there are no guarantees regarding what your program will do.